# connecting a mongodb created in mongolab through a java application

Tags: java, mongodb, mlab

i created a mongodb instance in mongolab
It provided me with a connection URI.

```
   mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds041177.mongolab.com:41177/myclouddb
```

I used the following java code to connect to my database-

```
      Mongo m = new Mongo();
     com.mongodb.DBAddress dba=new DBAddress("mongodb://admin:password@ds041177.mongolab.com:41177/myclouddb");
        m.connect(dba);
```

But this throws a NumberFormatException

```
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is a MongoDB URI.

Instead of passing it to a `DBAddress` just pass it to a `MongoURI` and then pass that to the `Mongo` instance.

```
String textUri = "mongodb://admin:password@ds041177.mongolab.com:41177/myclouddb";
MongoURI uri = new MongoURI(textUri);
Mongo m = new Mongo(uri);
```

You should also consider upgrading to the [latest](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads) driver and switching to the `MongoClient` class as the `Mongo` class is now deprecated.

```
String textUri = "mongodb://admin:password@ds041177.mongolab.com:41177/myclouddb";
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(textUri);
MongoClient m = new MongoClient(uri);
```

Comment: Is there any possibilitiesto set two host with username and password in MongoURI

Comment: You should be able to add the list of host/ports as a comma separated list: mongodb://admin:password@ds041177.mongolab.com:41177,ds041178.mongolab.com:41177/myclouddb. I am not sure that all drivers support this format but it is in the spec: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/